# SQL sequence not came out with right number

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DROP TABLE DEPT;
DROP SEQUENCE deptseq;

CREATE TABLE DEPT
(
 DEPTNO             NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
 DNAME              VARCHAR2(14),
 LOC                VARCHAR2(14),
 CONSTRAINT DEPT_PK PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE deptseq
INCREMENT BY 10
START WITH 10
NOMAXVALUE
NOCYCLE
NOCACHE;

INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (deptseq.NEXTVAL,'HR','NY');
```

This is the SQL I typed into Oracle SQL Developer. However, the first DEPTNO came out with 20. Why is that? I believe this suppose came out with 10.

Comment: A sequence guarantees a non-repeating, monotonically increasing sequence of numbers. It does *not* guarantee that they will be contiguous. If someone told you there would never, ever be any gaps in your number they **lied** to you, and you should demand they give you your money back.

Comment: @BobJarvis This is a duplicate but it's a little more subtle than the typical "why are there gaps?" problem.  tldr; Oracle may internally burn the first sequence when deferred segment creation is enabled.

Comment: the question I try to ask is why this is not started with 10? because I run this code before and it works properly. since I wrote START WITH 10 then it should be 10 and 20 - 30 - 40 .... but why this is started with 20 and go 30 - 40 - 50 ...... why 10 is missing?

Comment: [Here's an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32cfe/1) showing that the first value obtained from the sequence is 10. Share and enjoy.

Comment: BTW - is there a trigger which also grabs values from this sequence to populate DEPT.DEPTNO? If there is it would precisely explain this behavior.

Comment: To Bob Jarvis: I don't think there is anything going to affect the DEPTNO. I dunno why my sequence still start with 20. is there any difference between write INCREMENT BY 10 before START WITH 10 and write it reversely?

Answer (score 0):

#### You Just Run the Sequence It's Working

1st Parameter Start With then you can get below output:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE deptseq

START WITH 10 

INCREMENT BY 10

NOMAXVALUE
NOCYCLE
NOCACHE;
```

after run above sequence:

```
select deptseq.nextval from dual;

Output:
=========
10
```

Comment: This is not an answer since it is just a n exact copy from the question's code.

Comment: Your updated answer is unclear to me.